# Consider the set A = { x| x = (a+b)^3^n mod 3} where a and b is either 0 or 1, n is a positive integer. Determine the cardinality of the set A

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $A = \{ x \mid x = (a+b)^{3^n} \mod 3\}$ where $a$ and $b$ is either $0$ or $1$, $n$ is a positive integer. Determine the cardinality of the set $A$.

Not sure whether the answer is 3 or 4. Do we consider the null set?
Here is my approach but not sure whether if it is right :
since mod 3, possible value of $x$ would be $0,1,2$ only. hence cardinality = $3$

Comment: Is this a correct interpretation of the question: $A_{n}:=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid\left[x\equiv0\text{ mod }3\right]\vee\left[x\equiv1\text{ mod }3\right]\vee\left[x\equiv2^{3^{n}}\text{ mod }3\right]\right\} $
for $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. To find the cardinality of $A_{n}$?

Comment: yes this look similar

Comment: Note that if $x\in A$ then $x+3k \ in A$. So if your cardinality nonzero then you have at least countable cardinality of your set $A$.

Comment: Every multiple of $3$ is in it...?! Maybe $\mathbb Z$ must be replaced by $\mathbb Z_3$

Answer (score 0):

$A_{n}:=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid\left[x\equiv0\text{ mod }3\right]\vee\left[x\equiv1\text{ mod }3\right]\vee\left[x\equiv2^{3^{n}}\text{ mod }3\right]\right\}$$\subset\Big(\left\{ x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid\left[x\equiv0\text{ mod }3\right]\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid\left[x\equiv1\text{ mod }3\right]\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid\left[x\equiv2^{3^{n}}\text{ mod }3\right]\right\}$$\Big)$

Let $B_1=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid\left[x\equiv0\text{ mod }3\right]\}, B_2=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid\left[x\equiv1\text{ mod }3\right]\}, B_3=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid\left[x\equiv2^{3^{n}}\text{ mod }3\right]\right\}$

It easly seen that  $|B_i|=\omega$, $i=1,2,3$, so we know that countable union of  countable sets is countable, and then $A_n$ is countable.

($\omega$ is first infinite cardinal, the cardinality $A$ is denote by $|A|$)